# Cuda 7.5 and Visual Studio 2013: Some examples work, but other returns cudaErrorDevicesUnavailable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, cuda

I have installed recently CUDA 7.5 and Visual Studio 2013 in Windows 8.1. After testing examples, it worked perfectly for some, such as Mandelbrot or matrixMul. However, testing examples such as Marching Cubes and Bilateral Filtering, I'm getting the following error:

***"CUDA Runtime API error 46: all CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable"***

I've tested "deviceQuery" and it worked. Also, I'm using CUDA in a ASUS notebook with Geforce GT630m. I've tried setting the compute mode to DEFAULT, but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: The problem is related to graphics interop applications that are being run on an Optimus laptop.  Your laptop is using the Intel graphics device.  When an OpenGL or D3D context gets created, it is being created on the intel device.  You can force this to happen instead on the CUDA device (which is needed for proper CUDA/graphics interop) using one of several methods, one of which is to create an [application profile](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/optimus-developer-guide/index.html#applications-with-graphics-interoperability) in the NVIDIA display control panel.

Comment: It worked. Thank you!

Comment: Promote this comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most modern windows laptops with an Intel CPU that include an NVIDIA "discrete" GPU also use Intel "integrated" graphics in a cooperative arrangement, which NVIDIA brands [Optimus](http://www.nvidia.com/object/optimus_technology.html).

The basic idea is that the NVIDIA GPU will perform some graphics tasks, in some situations, but other tasks, perhaps in other situations, will be performed by the Intel graphics.

Typically, ordinary CUDA applications will run normally in this scenario.  The CUDA GPU is properly detected, and the CUDA runtime handles everything that is CUDA related on the NVIDIA GPU.

Graphics tasks that have no bearing on CUDA will also run either on the Intel or the NVIDIA device, according to an Optimus heuristic, the details of which are not relevant here.

However, for applications that use some form of graphics "Interop" with CUDA, some modification of the Optimus heuristic may be necessary.  CUDA/graphics interop [requires](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/optimus-developer-guide/index.html#applications-with-graphics-interoperability) that the CUDA "context" and graphics "context" both be established on the NVIDIA GPU (for the purposes of this question, where only one NVIDIA GPU is present).  If the graphics context is established first, and no consideration is given to this, then the graphics context may be established on the Intel device, and the CUDA graphics interop will fail in that scenario.

The solution is to force the graphics context to be established on the NVIDIA device for such applications, and the NVIDIA display driver control panel affords a mechanism (["profiles"](http://www.nvidia.com/object/profiles.html)) to make that happen.